# how to change dashboard admin

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, rbac

I ran

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding dashboard-admin -n default --clusterrole=cluste-admin --serviceaccount=default:dashboard
```

instead of

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding dashboard-admin -n default --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:dashboard
```

I would like to make the dashboard admin cluster-admin instead of cluste-admin

If I run

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding dashboard-admin -n default --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:dashboard
```

terminal outputs

Error from server (AlreadyExists): clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorizatoin.k8s.io "dashboard-admin" already exists

When I access the dashboard from a browser on the machine I am prompted for a token and am able to login as expected. I have numerous errors all ending in "cluste-admin" not found. I would like these to all go away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to make that happen now is you delete the `clusterrolebinding` and recreate it using:

```
kubectl delete clusterrolebinding dashboard-admin
kubectl create clusterrolebinding dashboard-admin -n default --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:dashboard
```

Comment: thank you very much worked like a charm very hard to find the delete command, greatly appreciated!